# File not found, but appears in directory

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-build

I am trying to run a docker build command to set up a container. When I run it, a file I need can't be found. I receive this error

```
/bin/sh: 1: ./downloadScript: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c ./downloadScript' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

I run `ls -la` before the script should run and it appears.

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Apr 30 18:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Apr 30 18:05 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  714 Apr 29 18:20 downloadScript
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Apr 30 18:05 gradleProject
```

I've tried a few things

- chmod 777 the file and directory
- cp the file, the chmod the new one (this new file can't be found either)
- reset docker credentials

My current script:

```
...
WORKDIR /dir1
RUN ls -la # For manual verification
RUN ./downloadScript
...
```

Docker output

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  120.3kB
Step 1/17 : FROM openjdk:8-slim as builder
 ---> e2581abdea18
Step 2/17 : WORKDIR /dir1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4ef289b22b45
Step 3/17 : ADD WCE_Docker/res /dir1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3d757ec6caba
Step 4/17 : ADD /GradleProject/ /dir1/gradleProject/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7e46cc77290d
Step 5/17 : WORKDIR /dir1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fe7570221d31
Step 6/17 : RUN ls -la
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 019ef7d640da
Step 7/17 : RUN ./downloadScript
 ---> Running in 9870fd1e3af3
/bin/sh: 1: ./downloadScript: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c ./downloadScript' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

It runs correctly on Mac and Ubuntu, but not on Windows 10.

**Update**

I manually setup the container and attempted to run the script and received a slightly different error.

```
root@835516a24a7f:/dir# ./downloadScript
bash: ./downloadScript: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Which I've found is DOS based line ends. I am going to fix that then post results.

**Update Results**

Ran `dos2unix downloadScript` and it worked correctly. The problem was DOS line ends.

Comment: What’s the `#!` line on the script?  Do you mistakenly have DOS line endings?

Comment: As a comment, its not actually there. The line is only ```RUN ls -la ```